# Trying to pull tabledata out from html

Tags: html, iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Basically I need to parse td(table data) from this html file.I need to get the right xpath.I am using raywenderlich as a model for this task, and here is the code I have so far.

```
  NSURL *tutorialsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/events];
NSData *tutorialsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tutorialsUrl];

// 2
TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:tutorialsHtmlData];

// 3

NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"This is where I need to enter my xpath to rerieve the table data";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];
```

I have the html path to this element thanks to firebug,which I will post below.

```
  /<html lang="en">/<body>/div id="page" class="container">/<div class="span-19">/<div id="content">/<div>/<table id=yw0 class="detail-view">/<tbody>/<tr class="even">/<td>moo</td>/
```

I need the text moo to be parsed. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

this is the x path I get from firebug as well, but it didn't work at all.

```
    /html/body/div/div[4]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to get substrings, where each substring contains one element that needs to be extracted:

```
    NSArray *split = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"<td>"];
```

In array "split", first object contains nothing you want, so you will not work with it anymore. Now, for each substring in this array (except first one) you need to search for substring with "/td" tag:

```
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"</td>"];
```

and then remove it and everything what is behind it:

```
    - (NSString *)substringToIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex //you will get index by searching for "</td>" as mentioned
```

EDIT:

Another possibility is to use componentsSeparatedByString even instead of 2nd and 3rd step for mentioned tag and in first item of each array, you will have wanted text.

EDIT2: (whole code)

```
    NSString* originalText = @"  /<html lang=""en"">/<body>/div id=""page"" class=""container"">/<div class=""span-19"">/<div id=""content"">/<div>/<table id=yw0 class=""detail-view"">/<tbody>/<tr class=""even"">/<td>moo1</td><td>moo2</td>/";
    NSArray* separatedParts = [originalText componentsSeparatedByString:@"<td>"];
    NSMutableArray* arrayOfResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 1; i < separatedParts.count; i++) {
           NSRange range = [[separatedParts objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:@"</td>"];
           NSString *partialResult = [[separatedParts objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:range.location];        
           [arrayOfResults addObject:partialResult];
    }
```

I have slightly altered original text to show that its really working for table with more items inside

Comment: I don't want to bother you too much, but might you be able to show me how this will work in my code? I am a little bit confused, but it seems you are very knowledgeable about this.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You just need to convert your NSData to NSString and use this string instead of my originalText